# How to remove periods in a string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the string `R.E.M`. and I need to make it `REM`

So far, I have:

```
$('#request_artist').val().replace(".", "");
```

...but I get `RE.M`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Part of the problem is that this is javascript, not jquery.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first argument to `replace()` is usually a regular expression.

Use the global modifier:

```
$('#request_artist').val().replace(/\./g, "");
```

[replace() at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 4):

You could pass a regular expression to the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and indicate that it should replace all occurrences like this: `$('#request_artist').val().replace(/\./g, '');`

Answer (score 2):

The method used to replace the string is not recursive, meaning once it found a matching char or string, it stop looking. U should use a regular expression replace. 
 `$("#request_artist").val().replace(/\./g, '');`
 Check out [Javascript replace tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php) for more info.